# Compute $\iint_D\cos{y^2}dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $$I=\iint_D\cos{y^2}dxdy,$$
>   where $D$ is the region bounded by the $y-$axis and the lines $y=x$, $y=\sqrt{\pi/2}$.

I've drawn the region and put the integration borders as follows:

[image]

So, $$I=\int_0^\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\int_x^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\cos{y^2}dx\right)dy.$$

But this involves some non-elementary functions so It can't be correct.

Comment: Is it $\cos(y^2)$ or $(\cos y)^2$ ?

Comment: It is $\cos{(y^2)}$

Comment: I know you've already accepted the answer below, but also note that $D$ is a [normal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Normal_domains_on_R2) on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: What do you mean by this and how will be useful to compute the integral? Doesn't matter if I accepted, If you can teach me something new, it's always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral doesn't make much sense as you wrote it. It must be

$$\int_0^{\sqrt\frac\pi2}\int_x^{\sqrt\frac\pi2}\cos y^2\,\color{red}{\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx}\stackrel{\text{Fubini}}=\int_0^{\sqrt\frac\pi2}\int_0^y\cos y^2\, \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_0^{\sqrt\frac\pi2}y\cos y^2\,\mathrm dy=$$

$$=\left.\frac12\sin y^2\right|_0^{\sqrt\frac\pi2}=\frac12\left(\sin\frac\pi2-\sin 0\right)=\frac12$$

Comment: Not learnt Fubini yet. What is that?

Comment: @Parseval  It allows you to change the order of integration. Perhaps you have just it as a claim or theorem...Anyway, you don't **really** need it here as you're **not** given a specific integral, just a domain over which to integrate. Thus, you can calmly *choose* to begin with the second integral above.

Comment: Ok but I'm not sure how you got that second integral. Can you elaborate on how you got $0$ to $y$ for the limits?

Comment: @Parseval there are two possible ways to write your domain with inequalities can you find that out?

Comment: Ok I see, now it makes sense. Thank you!